# how to upgrade to openoffice 3.1.1 on ubuntu jaunty

Tags: ubuntu, openoffice

I need to read some .docx files and the standard 3.0.1 version of OpenOffice writer that comes with Unbuntu 9.04 just ain't handling it.  I tried the instructions from the following site: http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Install-OpenOffice-org-3-1-on-Ubuntu-9-04-111105.shtml, both the GUI steps in the main article, and a scripted version in one of the comments, but my system never seems to do the partial update, and the OpenOffice version is unchanged after I uninstall and reinstall it from the command line.  Has anybody had similar problems?

Comment: They're already on version 3.2, just to let you know. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up being unable to upgrade, so I installed from downloaded .deb files using the instructions found here:

http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=68

Answer (score 0):

You should leave softpedia as it is.
Just open a Terminal and:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openoffice-pkgs/ppa`
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

(SoftPedia does it the same way but well.. try this out. Maybe you missed the update of your repositories or something.)